# VB.Net: Creating a StackRanking procedure with SQL Queires, for loops, and labels on Windows Form

Tags: sql, vb.net, for-loop, ranking, sqlcommand

I have a couple of questions regarding this code. Is there a better way to write these SQL statements so that i can probably just use one query? and the other question is regarding the

"Controls.Item("LblStckRnk" & i + 1).Text() = reader("EMPLOYEE")"

part of the code. What I want to do is give every "LblStckRnkXX" label a unique persons name based on the query but what is happening is that im getting one name 10 times.

Can anyone review this code (I know i can go to code review but Im already here) and help me out? This is the last part of my project, at work, and im done.

> Dim queryString(10) As String

```
            queryString(0) = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME AS EMPLOYEE, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE YEAR_TIME = " & cbYear.Text & " AND APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND ACTIVE = 1 GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            queryString(1) = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME AS EMPLOYEE, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE YEAR_TIME = " & cbYear.Text & " AND APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND ACTIVE = 1 AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            queryString(2) = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME AS EMPLOYEE, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE YEAR_TIME = " & cbYear.Text & " AND APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND ACTIVE = 1 AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk2.Text & "' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            queryString(3) = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME AS EMPLOYEE, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE YEAR_TIME = " & cbYear.Text & " AND APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND ACTIVE = 1 AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk2.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk3.Text & "' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            queryString(4) = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME AS EMPLOYEE, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE YEAR_TIME = " & cbYear.Text & " AND APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND ACTIVE = 1 AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk2.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk3.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk4.Text & "' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            queryString(5) = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME AS EMPLOYEE, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE YEAR_TIME = " & cbYear.Text & " AND APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND ACTIVE = 1 AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk2.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk3.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk4.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk5.Text & "' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            queryString(6) = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME AS EMPLOYEE, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE YEAR_TIME = " & cbYear.Text & " AND APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND ACTIVE = 1 AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk2.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk3.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk4.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk5.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk6.Text & "' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            queryString(7) = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME AS EMPLOYEE, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE YEAR_TIME = " & cbYear.Text & " AND APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND ACTIVE = 1 AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk2.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk3.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk4.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk5.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk6.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk7.Text & "' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            queryString(8) = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME AS EMPLOYEE, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE YEAR_TIME = " & cbYear.Text & " AND APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND ACTIVE = 1 AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk2.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk3.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk4.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk5.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk6.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk7.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk8.Text & "' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            queryString(9) = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME AS EMPLOYEE, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE YEAR_TIME = " & cbYear.Text & " AND APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND ACTIVE = 1 AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk2.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk3.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk4.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk5.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk6.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk7.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk8.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk9.Text & "' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""

            Using connection As New SqlConnection(SQLConnectionStr)
                For i As Integer = 0 To 9
                    Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString(i), connection)
                    If connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    Else
                        connection.Open()
                    End If
                    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                    While reader.Read()
                        Controls.Item("LblStckRnk" & i + 1).Text() = reader("EMPLOYEE")
                    End While
                    reader.Close()
                Next
            End Using
            '/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: First of all, don't concatenate your queries, use parameters. You're vulnerable to SQL injection now.

Comment: I have been hearing so much about SQL injections. When I get home, I'll go on lynda.com and learn about those. thanks. p.s. what do you mean by "don't concatenate your queries, use parameters"

Comment: Don't write queries like `"select * from table1 where id = " + id`. Use proper SQL parameters, e.g. `"select * from table1 where id = @id"`. Read more about SqlParameter on proper technical resources, e.g. MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following rewrite should get you what you are looking for:

```
    Const MAX_CONTROLS As Integer = 10

    ' Clear the existing controls
    For i = 0 To MAX_CONTROLS - 1
        Controls.Item("LblStckRnk" & i).Text = ""
    Next

    Dim queryString As String

    queryString = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME AS EMPLOYEE, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE YEAR_TIME = " & cbYear.Text & " AND APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND ACTIVE = 1 GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(SQLConnectionStr)
        Using command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
            connection.Open()

            Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                Dim i As Integer = 0

                While reader.Read() AndAlso i < MAX_CONTROLS
                    Controls.Item("LblStckRnk" & i).Text = reader("EMPLOYEE")
                    i += 1
                End While

                reader.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```